# How to prove the statement?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

> Say if is false or true that:
>
> > The sum or subtraction of two positive integer numbers not divisible by $3$ is always a
> >     multiple of $3$.

My attempt was:

I think that is true, because i can't get counterexamples for this statement, so i'll try to prove it.

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ the two numbers.

And, $\frac{a}{3} = \frac{p}{q}$, same for $b$,  $\frac{b}{3} = \frac{m}{n}$

Where $p,m \in \mathbb{Z}^+ - \{0\}$ and $q,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ -\{0,1\}$  and $p\neq q, m\neq n$, Also $\frac{p}{q}, \frac{m}{n}$ are simplified. These conditions ensure that $\frac{p}{q}, \frac{m}{n}$ are real numbers and not integers.

The sum of these numbers is equal to $3(\underbrace{\frac{p}{q}}_\text{a} +\underbrace{\frac{m}{n}}_\text{b})$

The substraction of these numbers is equal to  $3|(\frac{p}{q} - \frac{m}{n})|$

Thus i need to prove that the sum $\frac{pn+mq}{qn}$ is integer or the substraction $|(\frac{pn-mq}{qm})|$ is a integer.

But here I have arrived. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Why $3x+2$ instead of $3x+1$ ?

Comment: if a number is not divisible by $3$, then it is of the form $3k+1$ or $3k+2$

Comment: $1-2=-1$ try again.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee It says sum or subtraction. $1+2=3$.

Comment: So, the sum works when $a = 3k + 1, b = 3x +2$, then $a+b=3(k+x+1)$ And the substraction works when $a = 3k+1, b = 3x+1$, then $a-b = 3(k-x)$ , is this correct?

Comment: @EduardoS. Sounds good, but you missed the case where $a=3k+2$ and $b=3x+2$. It is simpler to consider the cases "same mod $3$" and "different mod $3$" in my opinion.

Comment: "I think that is true, because i can't get counterexamples for this statement,"  You didn't try $1 + 1 =2$?

Comment: This generalizes to any prime if we use little Fermat - see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a, b$ be two integers not divisible by $3$. Then, each of $a$ and $b$ are either $1$ or $2$ mod $3$.

If they are the same mod $3$, then $a-b\mod3=0$ so $a-b$ is divisible by 3.

If they are different mod $3$, then $a+b\mod3=0$ so $a+b$ is divisible by 3.

Answer (score 1):

True

We can represent these integers, not divisible by 3, as $3k+1$ and $3t+2$, $k,t \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now, look at the 4 possible $\pm$ cases. For simplicity, only the divisible case is written

- $3k+1 \pm 3t +1$

  - $3k+1 - 3t -1 = 3k -3t$ and $3| 3(k-t)$
- $3k+2 \pm 3t +2$

  - $3k+2 - 3t -2 = 3k -3t$ and $3| 3(k-t)$
- $3k+1 \pm 3t +2$

  - $3k+1 + 3t +2 = 3(k+t) +3$ and $3 | 3(k+t) +3$
- $3k+2 \pm 3t +1$

  - $3k+2 + 3t +1 = 3(k+t) +3$ and $3 | 3(k+t) +3$

For each case, we have a either plus or minus is divisible. Therefore the statement is true.

Comment: Be careful, you can't use the same variable $k$ for both numbers.

Comment: @79037662 The reason of that is because the numbers aren't necessary consecutive numbers?

Comment: @EduardoS. Correct.

Comment: Yes, Not necassary

Comment: @kelalaka Not fully corrected yet, you can't now say that $3k+1-3t-1=0$. Unless you meant to say it's equal to 0 mod 3.

Comment: @79037662 that part is forgotten when changing. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

$\bmod 3\!:\ a,b\not\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, a,b\equiv \color{#c00}{\pm1}\,\Rightarrow\,0\equiv\overbrace{ a^2-b^2}^{\textstyle\color{#c00}{ 1- 1}}\equiv (a\!-\!b)(a\!+\!b)$ $\overset{3\ \rm prime}\Longrightarrow \color{#0a0}{a\!-\!b}\equiv 0\,$ or $\,\color{#90f}{a\!+\!b}\equiv 0$

**Remark** $\ $ More generally applying little Fermat similarly yields

$\bmod p\!:\ a,b,\color{#0a0}{a\!-\!b}\not\equiv 0\,\overset{\rm Fermat}\Longrightarrow\,0\equiv\overbrace{ a^{p-1}-b^{p-1}}^{\textstyle\color{#c00}{ 1- 1}}$ $ \equiv (\color{#0a0}{a\!-\!b})\dfrac{a^{p-1}-b^{p-1}}{a-b}$ $\overset{p\ \rm prime}\Longrightarrow\, \color{#90f}{\dfrac{a^{p-1}-b^{p-1}}{a-b}}\equiv 0$